# How to convert unicode representation of non-ascii string to a python string as is?

Tags: python, string, unicode

How can I convert the unicode-representation of a non-ascii range string to a python string?

```
> str = '<some-arabic-content>'
> decoded_str = str.decode('utf-8')
> decoded_str
u'\u0623\u0646\u0633\u0646\u0629'
> str(decoded_str)
<WILL-THROW-AN-ERROR-OFC> since ascii cannot encode the unicode string
```

How do I get the this representation ('\u0623\u0646\u0633\u0646\u0629') as a python string? Like the one below.

```
> str_rep = '\u0623\u0646\u0633\u0646\u0629'
```

I want to land on `str_rep` from `decoded_str`. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: I recommend you try python3.x to solved this kind of problems(encode/decode) of python2.x

Comment: Don't use `str` as variable name.

Comment: @danielfranca : python 2.7.6

Comment: @Wonka : Unfortunately I cannot move to python 3.x (working in a team)

Comment: @Rakesh_K : apologies for that. I actually wrote the code instead of copying it from my prompt. This is just for explanation sake.

Comment: I also recommend to move to Python3... otherwise read this article to get a better understanding on how unicode works on Python2: https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decoded_str.encode("unicode-escape")` produces the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to print your variable decoded_str??

```
foo = u'\u0623\u0646\u0633\u0646\u0629'

print(foo)

أنسنة

print(repr(foo))
u'\u0623\u0646\u0633\u0646\u0629'
```

Comment: I want to print the unicode representation itself as a string. Not the encoded output in arabic. I want the printed string to be '\u0623\u0646\u0633\u0646\u0629'

Comment: ooh ok, try: print(repr(foo))

Comment: This works too! Thanks a lot! :D The answer by @jasonharper also works.

Comment: No problem, continue with the "amazing world of python encoding", im updating all my script to python3.x to solved this